# Laravel | Pivot table, table names clashing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am trying to create a pivot table in order to link Teachers to a Subject, which will then link the teacher to a subject.

I have the teachers table schema like this.

```
| id | first_name | last_name | created_at | updated_at
```

And the pivot table schema like this.

```
| id | teacher_id | subject_id
```

And the subject table schema like this.

```
| id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

It is a very basic table structure whilst I try and figure out the ins and outs.

I have this code inside of my `Teacher.php` model which extends Eloquents Model.

The teacher can have multiple subjects assigned to them.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TeacherSubject', 'teacher_subjects', 'teacher_id', 'id');
```

This is the error that I am getting..

> Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'teacher_subjects' (SQL: select teacher_subjects.*, teacher_subjects.teacher_id as pivot_teacher_id, teacher_subjects.id as pivot_id from teacher_subjects inner join teacher_subjects on teacher_subjects.id = teacher_subjects.id where teacher_subjects.teacher_id in (1))

To me it seems as though for whatever reason the `belongsToMany` is renaming both tables to be the same name, which is confusing me entirely.

Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Comment: You don't need a separate model for the pivot table. `$this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class)` (and `Subject::class` on the teacher) should work

Comment: That worked perfectly! Only change I had to make was `$this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'teacher_subjects')`. can you put this as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pivot table does not need a model, laravel handles the relationships for you. Just use:

Teachers model

```
 $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'teacher_subjects');
```

Subjects model

```
 $this->belongsToMany(Teacher::class, 'teacher_subjects');
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need an intermediary model, but sometimes it makes sense (i.e. when you can have multiple relationships between two entities, like in a historic log table with valid_from and valid_until fields). In this case it makes sense to keep it easy, though.

Comment: @Namoshek that's what using the `pivot` and `withPivot` methods are for so even then an intermediate model is unnecessary

Comment: I haven't found a way to properly update pivot values when multiple relations exist between two entities. To stick with the example from the documentation, `$user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);` will update both relations if you have attached the same role twice to your user (with different pivot values).

Comment: In that case you use `withPivot` and then filter based on a given attribute by `$model->pivot->attribute`.

Comment: @Namoshek that's an interesting point but the real question is does the table you describe really fall under the category of a pivot table? Furthermore can you have the same foreign key pair multiple times in a many to many relationship and still be allowed to call it  many to many relationship? It seems that Laravel took a hard line on this and is saying your use case is not a pivot but an entity on its own right.